# SQL, put most common countries at top and then all the rest below

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to create a select field that shows all the countries but puts the UK, US, CA, NZ and AU at the top and then all the rest below but in alphabetical order! I'm unsure how to go about this and have searched through StackOverflow but have yet to find a solution.

```
public function getCountries()
{
    $results = $this->db->select('msi_countries','status = 1 ORDER BY sorting DESC');
    return $results;
}
```

My db table goes as follows:

```
id | cc | name | status | sorting
------------------------------
1  | ?? | afff | 1      | 0
2  | ?? | vccc | 1      | 0
....
....
121  | AU | Australia   | 1      | 1
122  | NZ | New Zealand | 1      | 2
etc.
```

And then I attempted to order by sort DESC and thought it would then go back to the first country again but it did not work so I was wondering how I go about completing this task where I put the top countries at the top like this and then the rest are below!:

```
country
country
country
country
-----------------
rest of countries
```

Thanks

Comment: What didn't work? Hard to tell what you're asking as it's written.   If you want to have the countries in two different sort orders, you'll likely need 2 queries (or a subquery) or to sort them in PHP.

Comment: @Devon thanks for your quick reply, please can you show me what you mean! Thanks

Comment: @BobMars, well, what does sorting mean?  Is a sorting of `0` mean the "rest" and a sorting of `>0` mean common in this context?  You assume we know what your fields in the database mean.

Comment: As @Devon mentions... if you already have a column called "sorting", which has the specific sort order of your main countries... and all 'the rest` set to zero... that screws with the ordering. Set 'all the rest' to like `999999` ;) Then `ORDER BY sorting ASC, name ASC` works as expected.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Thanks and why did i get a -1? This was a valid question that I found difficult to answer and I could not find any others on Stackoverflow?

Comment: Don't ask me ;) I don't downvote unless something is really a terrible or useless question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question well, but if you want to show the biggest `sorting` countries first and the ones with zero later (these ones ordered by name), then the query should look like:

```
select * 
  from msi_countries
  order by sorting desc, name
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks but @IncredibleHat had the solution! Works great :)